# aiohttp RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I'm trying to create the simplest web application on aiohttp:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def run_app2(request):
    return web.Response(text="Done")

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.post('/post', run_app2)])
web.run_app(app)
```

Nothing superfluous, but for some reason the error RuntimeError is raised:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Python 3.10.10, aiohttp 3.8.4, i run the program in the IDE Spyder